# How to assess if an observation fits a non normal sample

Tags: p-value

I am trying to find if a case observation fits in a sample distribution for a specific variable. My interest is to evaluate if an event occurring in a patient alters gene expression. The problem is that each event ir particular and it occurs just in one patient. So, what I do is to look for differences between the level of expression of the gene where the event happens in the case patient and the rest of the patients (which lack that event).

This is an example of my data:

```
sampleid expr status
sampleA 86.6 control
sampleB 34.2 control
sampleC 78.1 control
sampleD 77.1 control
sampleE 66.0 control
sampleF 90.5 control
sampleG 160.2 case
sampleH 31.2 control
sampleI 100.1 control
sampleJ 10.9 control
sampleK 23.4 control
```

My interest is to assess if there are interesting differences between case sample and control group. On the one hand I have calculated a log fold change between case expr and the median of controls expr. However, I would also like to obtain something like a p-value to assess its significance.

I know that I could see if the value is greater than 2 fold the sd of the control group expression, but as I am not working with normal distributed samples, I am not sure about how to proceed.

Do you know how can I achieve this?

Comment: This would benefit from some context --- is this a question about if `case` is an outlier?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I have just eddited the question to include some context. I think that's not my interest. I would like to check the significance of the impact on gene expression of an event which only occurs in one patient.